# Sequence of short exact sequences - does it impose that inverse limits of the terms of the sequence form a short exact sequence?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, modules, exact-sequence

I've recently started working on my research project. My supervisor explained to me what exact sequences are and how to construct an inverse limit. I want to apologise for probably not the best language to describe my problem. He asked me a question:

Suppose that we have a sequence of modules and exact sequences: $0\to M_{n}\to N_{n}\to L_{n}\to 0$

Such that for all n:

$p_{n}: M_{n} \to N_{n}$

$q_{n} : N_{n} \to L_{n}$

$p_{n}$ is injective.
$q_{n}$ is surjective.
And we also have $Im(p_{n}) = ker(q_{n})$.

Does this impose that:
$0\to$ inverse limit of $M_{n}\to$ inverse limit of $N_{n}\to$ inverse limit of $L_{n}\to0$?

Are there any pathological situations?

With:
p: inverse limit of $M_{n}\to$ inverse limit of $N_{n}$

q: inverse limit of $N_{n}\to$ inverse limit of $L_{n}$

$$\mathrm{Im}(p)=\mathrm{ker}(q)$$

I've proven that if inverse limits "stop changing after some time" (sequences of $M_{n}$, $N_{n}$, $L_{n}$ are finite), then this is true. I did this by assigning $p$ coordinate by coordinate - for example, $p( (x_{1}, x_{2}, \dots, x_{n})) = ( p_{1}(x_{1}),p_{2}(x_{2}), \dots, p_{n}(x_{n}) )$. Analogously with $q_{n}$.

I've been thinking that I might show those pathologies with either a ring with non-zero characteristic, or by chosing one of inverse limits not being closed.

For example: $M_{n}$ = ring of polynomials with variable $x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ with degree $n$ and $0$th coefficient being equal to $0$,
$N_{n} = R^{n+1}$
with $p_{n}(f_{n}) = (f_{n}(0), f_{n}(1), \dots, f_{n}(n+1))$
And $L_{n} = R$
And $q_{n} = \Pi^{n+1}_{1}f(i)$
Then I'd look at the sequence defined as $y_{n} \in M_{n}$ with $y_{n}(x) = \sum_{1}^{n+1}\frac{x^k}{k!}$. Then in the inverse limit of $x$ we'd have $e^x-1$, which is not a rational, creating a "pathology" (???).

I'm looking for hints/tips/ resources where I could figure out this stuff on my own. Please don't use the language of cathergory theory, I'm just a second year bachelor student...

Comment: Try showing that $0\rightarrow\lim M_n\rightarrow\lim N_n\rightarrow\lim L_n$ is exact. There are categorical reasons this holds and I think you ought to learn them at some point, but this is simple enough so that you can do it completely explicitly "by hand". It is not true in general that the right arrow $\lim N_n\rightarrow\lim L_n$ is surjective. Try coming up with counter-examples or see what the obstructions are. There's a more general theory lying behind this involving a so-called derived limit, but this needs the language of homological algebra.